# How to get a variable from another file after its defined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, module, node-modules

I'm trying to get the mongo client in another file. The problem is, when I try getting the mongoClient variable, it returns undefined.

How can I wait till a the mongoClient variable is declared before trying to get it?

**File 1**

```
let mongoClient;

module.exports = async function() {
    const mongooseOptions = {...};
    mongoClient = await mongoose.connect(dbUrl, mongooseOptions);
};

exports.getMongoClient = () => mongoClient;
```

**File 2**

```
const { getMongoClient } = require('../../startups/db');
console.log(getMongoClient); // Returns undefined
```

Comment: Is this not working `getMongoClient.then(...)` in your File 2 ?

Comment: @AhmetZeybek I get an error saying Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You should use this logic

**File 1**

```
const axios = require("axios");
async function getData() {
  return await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
}
module.exports = { getData };
```

**File 2**

```
const { getData } = require("./file1");
getData().then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: That would work, but I want to call it in multiple files. If I do it this way, then `getData` will refetch the data every time it gets called, or in my case, the mongodb would reconnect every time this gets called, which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **global** variable for access in in any file like as bellow.

File 1

```
global.mongoClient;

module.exports = async function() {
    const mongooseOptions = {...};
    global.mongoClient = await mongoose.connect(dbUrl, mongooseOptions);
};
```

File 2

```
console.log(global.getMongoClient);
```